# Return result disappears in Python recursive function

Tags: python, string, recursion

The assignment was to write a recursive function lenRecur(s) that returns the length of a string s.  Slicing is allowed, obviously the len() function is not. After struggling with the code below for too long, the answer dawned on me: it's virtually the proverbial "one line of code," so simple!  What follows is *NOT* the "correct" answer, but I would still like to know why it doesn't work.  I was trying to recursively decompose the string and count the number of steps with an index, but the index was reset to 0 each time, so I thought to create an inner function, countRecur(s,i), that takes s *and* an initial index as argument and augments the index with each recursion. The final index would be returned to the outer function.  Bottom line:  the index cranks up properly, yet return i returns None.

```
def lenRecur(s):    
    i=0  

    def countRecur(s,i):         
        if s == "":                        
            print "final i  =   ", i
            return i    
        else:
            i+=1            
            print s
            s = countRecur(s[:-1],i)              

    p = countRecur(s,i)    
    return p
s = "abc"
q = lenRecur(s)    
print q
```

Here is the output:

```
abc
ab
a
final i  =    3
None
```

Comment: Defining a function in a function is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not returning `s`, which you should probably change to `i` since it's the count when `s` is the string originally. When you don't return it you essentially throw away s and p is never set.

```
def lenRecur(s):    
    i=0  

    def countRecur(s,i):         
        if s == "":                        
            print "final i  =   ", i
            return i    
        else:
            i+=1            
            print s
            i = countRecur(s[:-1],i)
        return i

    p = countRecur(s,i)
    return p
s = "abc"
q = lenRecur(s)    
print q

abc
ab
a
final i  =    3
3
```

Comment: Thanks so much!   With your change, plus a small tweak, the outer function and the passed parameter "i" can be dispensed with altogether!

Comment: @PatrickDennis no problem. Don't forget to accept the answer to help people in the future